# WordPress search redirecting to unwanted random pages

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, search

I took on the development of a site that has a custom theme and some custom plugins ([here's the site link](https://literaryconsultancy.co.uk)). I had to migrate this from shared hosting to a newer WP install on an AWS server so that I could utilise some better server-side tools.

Since migrating, the search function has simply kaputted in a very baffling way: it just dithers, then redirects to random pages depending on where you are in the site.

As far as I can tell it is the standard WP search engine, with a few custom page params in index.php for the search results page. I've commented out the custom params, re-built the search index, disabled all plugins, and added the default search.php template from the parent theme, but still no joy.

Has anyone got any idea what could be going on?

Comment: check the action in searchform.php

Comment: Can you provide any code? It's impossible to tell without seeing what you've actually got there...